# Extract/Decompile source files from exe

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, decompiling, reflector, .net-reflector

There is a client specific solution that we cannot find the source code for, but we do have the .exe file.

Is it possible to use .Net Reflector to extract this into a buildable solution within Visual Studio?

At the moment I can retrieve some of the .cs files, but the forms within the application, as well as the folder structures etc. do not extract.

Is there some plugin I can use to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for .Net Reflector plugins only, then you can try ReflectorFileDisassembler:

http://www.denisbauer.com/Home/ReflectorFileDisassembler

One more .Net Reflector plugin is FileGenerator:

http://filegenreflector.codeplex.com/

If you are open for alternatives another option would be JustDecompile by Telerik:

http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx

Dotpeek is also an option, as mentioned by other answers.

Comment: The FileDisassembler did the trick, although it required some extra work from my side.

Comment: Nice. I am glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

[dotPeek](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/tag/dotpeek-1-2/) can turn assemblies into actual `.sln` or `.csproj` files. My experience with all of those tools is that they can do decent jobs, but sometimes it's just not possible to turn compiled assemblies back to original.